# Filter a dataframe by a column if a condition is met in another column with Dplyr R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I haven't been able to find the answer to my question anywhere. I have an R dataframe, and I would like to filter by the value of a column if a condition is met in another column else the value shouldn't be filetered, and I would ideally do this using Dplyr.

In the case of my dataframe, I would like to filter those values (third column) lesser than 1 only in those cases in which type is "real".

```
# My Dataframe 
dat = data.frame(dte = c("2011-01-01","2011-02-01","2011-03-01","2011-04-01","2011-05-01",
                          "2011-01-01","2011-02-01","2011-03-01"),
                  type = c("real","real","real","real","real","ts","ts","ts"),
                  value=rnorm(8))

# Desired output

         dte type      value
1 2011-01-01 real -1.0852682
3 2011-03-01 real -0.6664113
4 2011-04-01 real -0.7394061
5 2011-05-01 real -2.3819627
6 2011-01-01   ts -1.2122576
7 2011-02-01   ts  1.0923944
8 2011-03-01   ts -2.0373596
```

I tried this but it did not work whatsoever.

```
dat1 <- dat %>% filter(if(type == "real") value < 1 else value == value )
```

Anyone can give me any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Rachael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use :

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% filter(type == "real" & value < 1 | type != "real")
```

We can use the same condition in base R `subset` as well

```
subset(dat, type == "real" & value < 1 | type != "real")
```